# Nest grpc client is not communicating with the grpc server

Tags: grpc, nestjs

I was trying to implement a simple grpc service in my nest js project but unfortunately my client is not communicating with the server. I am sharing
some codes below. It will be really helpful if anyone can give me some insights of whats going wrong.

--------- GRPC Server -------

Main.ts file looks like this.

```
 async function setUpGrpc(grpcUrl){
   const grpcApp = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(GrpcModule, {
   transport: Transport.GRPC,
   options: {
    package: 'protos.user',
    url : grpcUrl,
    protoPath: join(__dirname, '/protos/user.proto'),
    },
   });
   return grpcApp;
}

async function bootstrap() {
   const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
   const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
   const port = configService.get('PORT');

   const grpcUrl = configService.get('GRPC_URL');
   console.log(grpcUrl);
   const grpcApp = await setUpGrpc(grpcUrl);

   await grpcApp.listen(()=>{
     console.log("Grpc is listening")
   });
   await app.listen(port);
  }
bootstrap();
```

GrpcModule

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    SequelizeDbModule,
  ],
  controllers: [GrpcUserController],
  providers: [],
})
export class GrpcModule {}
```

GrpcUserController

```
interface IUserInfo {
  userName: string;
  passWord: string;
  tenantId: string;
}
interface IUser {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  tenantId: string;
}

@Controller()
export class GrpcUserController {
  constructor() {}

   @GrpcMethod('UserValidationService', 'ValidateUser')
   validateUser(userInfo: IUserInfo, metaData: any) : IUser {
    console.log('Call is made');

    return {name:'Test',phone:'Test',email:"Test@Test",tenantId:"TestTenant",id:'TestId'};
  }
}
```

My Proto file looks like this.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package protos.user;

service UserValidationService {
  rpc ValidateUser (UserInfo) returns (User) {}
}

message UserInfo {
  string userName = 1;
  string passWord = 2;
  string tenantId = 3;
}

message User {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string email = 3;
  string phone = 4;
  string tenantId = 5;
}
```

------ Client --------

Used the same protofile

I made the client as a nest library

```
@Injectable()
export class UserGrpcClientService implements OnModuleInit {

  userValidationService:IUserValidationService;

  @Client( {
    transport: Transport.GRPC,
    options: {
      package: 'protos.user',
      url : "localhost:5000",
      protoPath: join(__dirname, '/protos/user.proto'),
    },
  })
  client : ClientGrpc
  constructor(){}

  onModuleInit() {
     this.userValidationService = this.client.getService<IUserValidationService('UserValidationService');
    console.log(this.userValidationService);
  }

    validateUser(userInfo: IUserInfo) : Observable<any>{

     console.log("Inside validateUser");
     console.log(JSON.stringify(userInfo));
     return  this.userValidationService.validateUser({userName:userInfo.userName,
                                                passWord:userInfo.passWord,
                                                tenantId:userInfo.tenantId}); 
  }
}
```

interfaces

```
export interface IUserInfo {
  userName: string;
  passWord: string;
  tenantId: string;
}
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  tenantId: string;
}

export interface IUserValidationService{
  validateUser (UserInfo : IUserInfo) : Observable<any>
}
```

I have integrated this client library in another running nest application.

```
  @Post('auth/token')
  @HttpCode(200)
  async token(
    @Body() tokenRequest: TokenRequestDTO,
    @Headers() headers,
  ): Promise<Object> {
    this.logger.info('Inside token request');

    this.helper.validateRequestBody(tokenRequest);
    this.helper.validateHeader(headers);

    var response =  this.userGrpcClient.validateUser({
      userName: 'test',
      passWord: 'test',
      tenantId: 'test',
    })

    console.log(response);
    return await this.authService.provideToken(tokenRequest, headers);
  }
```

when I run this, there is no error. the response that I logged shows
Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }

Comment: getting same error. Any solution?

Comment: Hi, you have to subscribe. GRPC client will return an observable

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when calling the validateUser function using the userGrpcClient it returns an observable and I have to subscribe on it.